# Boolean Algebra - $ABC+B'=AC+B'$?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm doing a bit of homework, and it says to prove or disprove the statement

$XZ+X'Y'+Y'Z'=XZ+Y'$

If you do a truth table and take the sum-of-products, you can eventually simplify the equation down to $XYZ+Y'$. Now that was way too close for me to stop there, and I couldn't think of anything beyond that. I plugged it into one of the WolframAlpha Boolean Algebra equators and it came out with $XYZ+Y'=XZ+Y'$. I'm perplexed as to how it got that, or if it's just a bug in the program.

The only thing I can think of is that it is an extension on the $A+A'B=A+B$ law, but I'm not entirely sure that can be used on $3$ different variables like this. Can someone explain if this is the legitimate answer, and if so can you please prove it so I can see how that's true? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

XZ + Y' = XZY +XZY' + Y' = XYZ + (XZY' +Y') 
 XZY' is a subset of Y'. So, 
 =XYZ + Y'

Best thing to do would be draw three intersecting circles as X,Y and Z and try to visualize LHS and RHS

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\bar{Y} \implies X\bar{Y}Z$ and so $ \bar{Y}  = X\bar{Y}Z + \bar{Y}$.

Then
$ XYZ+ \bar{Y} = XYZ+ X\bar{Y}Z + \bar{Y}= X(Y+\bar{Y})Z + \bar{Y} = XZ + \bar{Y}$.

Answer (score 0):

> *ABC + B’ = AC + B’* ?

The expression on the left means `if B then AC, if not B then true.` Obviously, the *repeated* mentioning of *B* is *redundant*, so the expression to the right, which reads `if not B then true, else AC` is its simplified equivalent. You can verify this by writing $B'+ABC=B'+BAC=$ $=(B'+B)(B'+AC)=1\cdot(B'+AC)=AC+B'.$